# Java popup sending multiple action

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jdialog

The first popup would only send one action, the second would send two, third will be three so and so forth. I was able to narrow it down to it being the button sending action multiple time.

At first, I was using jframe for all my window, so I tried using jdialog, the problem persists. tried making it so that when the user clicks on the button the window is disposed, still don't fix it.

```
public class BoothDetails extends JDialog implements ActionListener{

    FloorPlanGUI floorPlan = new FloorPlanGUI();

    static JLabel bname = new JLabel();
    JTextArea details = new JTextArea();
    static JButton addsche = new JButton("ADD TO SCHEDULE");
    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();

    public BoothDetails(String name, String detail) {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        bname.setText(name);
        details.setText(detail);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 10, 10));
        northPanel.add(bname);
        northPanel.add(addsche);
        addsche.addActionListener(floorPlan);
        addsche.addActionListener(this);

        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(details, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `setVisible(true); setSize(300, 200);` Get rid if the guesswork on the size. Instead `pack()` to get the right size once all components are added. `setVisible(true)` should be last.

Answer (score 0):

```
static JLabel bname = new JLabel();
JTextArea details = new JTextArea();
static JButton addsche = new JButton("ADD TO SCHEDULE");
```

Don't use the `static` keyword. This means the variable is shared by all instances of the class.

So every time you create a new instance of the class you execute the following code:

```
addsche.addActionListener(floorPlan);
```

which adds another ActionListener to the button.

The static keyword is should generally only be used when you create constant variables in your class, it should NOT be used for components which need to be unique for each class.

Comment: i use static on addsche and bname is because i wanted to be able to access them in another class without having to create another object for BoothDetails class, and if i do create a new object, i would also have to create a empty constructor in BoothDetails class. 

code:
if (a.getActionCommand() == BoothDetails.addsche.getActionCommand()) {
   Schedule.addSchedule(BoothDetails.bname.getText());
  }

if (a.getActionCommand().equals(bth1.getActionCommand())) {
   BoothDetails boothDetails = new     BoothDetails(dataBase.boothname1, dataBase.boothdetails1);
  }